# Cannot label dendrograms in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a hierarchical analysis using Hclust(), but I can't get the names of each case to appear in the dendrogram. Only their numerical identifier appears. The strange thing is that I do the same procedure with my data and with the USArrests database integrated in R. With USArrests it works very well, but not with my data frame, which is built by importing it from Excel.

This I do with my data (df2, a data frame):

> d2<-hclust(dist(df2))
> Warning message:
> In dist(df2) : NAs introduced by coercion

Then plot(d2, hang = -1) delivers the dendrogram, but not the label names, only the numerical identifier.

The warning I think is for the names of the observations, which are characters, but the USArrests base also has a character variable, and the dendrogram appears with the names of the labels. The only difference I see is that in my data, the names of the observations appear justified on the right, and in USArrests on the left:

```
> head(USArrests)
           Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
Alabama      13.2     236       58 21.2
Alaska       10.0     263       48 44.5
Arizona       8.1     294       80 31.0
Arkansas      8.8     190       50 19.5
California    9.0     276       91 40.6
Colorado      7.9     204       78 38.7
> head(df2)
            Mort_inf Esp_Vida_M Esp_vida_H
1 Argentina     25.6         75         68
2  Barbados     20.3         78         73
3   Bolivia     75.0         64         59
4    Brazil     66.0         67         57
5     Chile     14.6         78         71
6  Colombia     28.0         75         69
```

I don't understand what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Luis

The result of dput() is:

```
> dput(head(df2))
structure(list(c("Argentina", "Barbados", "Bolivia", "Brazil", 
"Chile", "Colombia"), Mort_inf = c(25.6, 20.3, 75, 66, 14.6, 
28), Esp_Vida_M = c(75, 78, 64, 67, 78, 75), Esp_vida_H = c(68, 
73, 59, 57, 71, 69)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks...

Comment: Can you post some of your data using `dput`?

Comment: In `USArrests` those names are not a *variable*, they are the `rownames`. Can you post the output of `dput(head(df2))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tip labels in the dendrogam correspond to the row.names in the data.frame object. Try the following:

```
row.names(df2)<-df2[,1]
```

Here's the resulting dendrogram

[image]